# Blender Puple Mesh issue with texturing

Tags: texturing

Im still new to blender but I found this problem... Im using the latest version and I found out, 
I had a small project with a TON of textures and was looking really good, but I came back online 
the following day and I found that all my textures have turned purple??? I have no idea what happened
 but all the original textures have disappeared. If anyone could help that would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use search before posting your questions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes this is a really common issue and im surprised that it hasn't been answered before... its imply just saying that your mesh has no material data, so say you have allocated it to a image texture node, you have no image set to it (no image data for the mesh). so make sure you have at least one material properties to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh thank you so much aplan, this worked just fine

Comment: You're welcome! If you have any other questions feel free to ask!